# How to perform a transaction with an Entity Framework object context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

I created very a simple database using Entity Framework 4.  I'd like to be able to use transactions on entities, but I can't seem to keep changes from rolling back.  I really just need a way to abandon temporary changes to entities before they are saved to the database.

For example, the following code uses an entity framework object context "MusicContainer".  Inside a TransactionScope, an Artist entity is created.  The transaction then ends without being completed; so I'd expect the transaction to be rolled back.  But, the program runs as if I'd never created the TransactionScope in the first place; after the TransactionScope ends, the line music.SaveChanges() saves the object to the database.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MusicContainer music = new MusicContainer())
        {
            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Artist artist = new Artist { Name = "Test" };
                music.Artists.AddObject(artist);
            }
            // The transaction ended without Complete(); shouldn't the changes be abandoned?
            music.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

If entity framework doesn't use TransactionScope the way I'm expecting it to here, how can I get the functionality I'm looking for?  I have several circumstances where the caller of a function passes in the MusicContainer, and I need to leave the MusicContainer in a clean state before I return from the function (i.e. rolling back changes so they don't accidently get saved in with another SaveChanges called on the same MusicContainer object).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a `TransactionScope` at all in this scenario, `SaveChanges()` is all that's needed - if you have another `using` block with `MusicContainer`, this will be in a separate transaction and won't save any changes within your current `using` block. `TransactionScope` is only needed for transactions spanning multiple DB contexts.

In general a context should only be used for a unit of work consisting of related operations, once they are completed call `SaveChanges()`. Open a new context for each separate, unrelated unit of work. Having said that, just use this in your scenario:

```
        using (MusicContainer music = new MusicContainer())
        {
                Artist artist = new Artist { Name = "Test" };
                music.Artists.AddObject(artist);
                music.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I use a separate "using (MusicContainer music = new MusicContainer())" for each transaction?  My first suspicion was that this would be a bottleneck if I have dozens of these going on in parallel--am I wrong to think that?

Comment: @notfed I believe the overhead is minimal - DB connections are only used by EF when needed, i.e. when calling `SaveChanges()` or doing a query, also check out this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx

Comment: @notfed: You must use new container for each transaction. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I knew I was approaching some aspect of this from the wrong angle, and this helped smack some sense back into me.

Answer (score 2):

You have your SaveChanges in the wrong place.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MusicContainer music = new MusicContainer())
        {
            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Artist artist = new Artist { Name = "Test" };
                music.Artists.AddObject(artist);
                music.SaveChanges();
            }
            // The transaction ended without Complete(); the changes are abandoned?
        }
    }
}
```

You shouldn't reuse your `MusicContainer` if the transaction fails.  Create a new one for each [Unit of Work](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)

Comment: I have the SaveChanges in the wrong place on purpose.  My point is: in the code I've given, why is SaveChanges saving those changes?

Comment: You have to declare the TransactionScope before the MusicContainer.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework should be able to use ***TransactionScope***. You need to start a New TransactionScope if you need to rollback the changes apllied only by this method.

```
 using (MusicContainer music = new MusicContainer())
   {
     using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOptions.RequiresNew))
          {
              Artist artist = new Artist { Name = "Test" };
              music.Artists.AddObject(artist);
              music.SaveChanges();
              scope.Complete(); 
          }
    }
```

Comment: Well, if I'm being passed a MusicContainer from a caller function, I don't have the option the create the MusicContainer inside the TransactionScope.

Comment: Then you don't need to call SaveChanges in your method. Let the top level function call the SaveChanges

Comment: But, I need to _abandon_ changes that have been made to the object context, and I don't want the caller to save those changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out, but that still doesn't work :/.  I think, as the other answers are pointing out, that I should really just use the container itself as my transaction.